# Any way to use Skype without random crashes? Like another gui?

Tags: xorg, skype

Okay here's the deal, there is a bug about this (or so it seems) that I reported (it's been changed **a lot** since then); Skype is crashing and random/on clicks (e.g. adding a contact). I'm tired of Skype, but unfortunately I don't rule the world and I can make anyone switch. Are there any alternate clients? Like something I can use to connect to Skype, add contacts, and chat? Video support would be nice, but it's optional. I know SkypeKit needs a payment first, so it's unlikely anyone has made anything with it, but, I'm DESPERATE right now -__- (the crashing has made me lose stuff, so I'm a bit... you know).

ANYTHING that works would be GREATLY appreciated.

I'll use ekiga for contacts who don't care about Skype, but some won't switch so ekiga is off the list :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found something myself, and I think this might be useful for other users:

[imo.im](https://imo.im/) allows you to chat, even with video, on Skype and other similar services (MSN, etc). The cool part, and perhaps the drawback, is that it is a website, so you have to have a browser window open. To work around this "limitation" I'm planning to use prism, so I can have a desktop application (though it looks better in webkit).

Comment: imo.im is awesome alright. HTML5 FTW!

Answer (score 5):

You can install the [pidgin-skype](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pidgin-skype) package from the Ubuntu Software Centre which (despite the name) will allow you to use Skype in both Empathy (the Ubuntu default IM client) and Pidgin.

From the package description:

> This plugin communicates with the Skype application in the background to perform its work, so it's necessary to have Skype installed and running. This product uses the Skype API but is not endorsed, certified or otherwise approved in any way by Skype.

Comment: last time I used this was a long time ago, can it add contacts? I forgot.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use pidgin and this plugin

[eion.robbmob.com](http://eion.robbmob.com/)

Eion's plugin will let you use skype from within pidgin you still need to have skype running but you won't have to use the gui. It is available in the software centre as pidgin-skype

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be asking two different questions here, so I'll address the first ("Any way to use Skype without random crashes?") only, since others appear to have addressed the second ("Are there any alternate clients? Like something I can use to connect to Skype, add contacts, and chat?").  To properly debug and finally resolve the reason(s) for the crashes, you'll need to use gdb and strace on the actual skype binary.  Also, you'll likely have better luck providing said information to the Skype developers.

Comment: it's one question, skype is a service. and I did file a bug with Skype's developers, they never even acknowledged that they got it.

Comment: Perhaps, then, you can provide that information in your bug report and link to it here?

Comment: my bug report is technically no longer "mine" it got edited so much, it no longer even refers to the same problem. I stopped paying attention after a while.